# Decide according to the condition and display the content dynamically in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html

Whenever error occurs, I need to display the exception message in HTML page.

Basically my HTML page has a form called "My_formG".

I need to display the exception content ( *or at least a normal statement/sentence "try it again"*) above the form "My_formG".

For that I **tried the code**,

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php

    $MyexceptionOverFlow=1;

    if(isset($MyexceptionOverFlow))
    {
    ?>
   <div>
   <?php echo " OVER FLOW EXCEPTION.......  ";?>      
   </div>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   <form id="My_formG">
   Enter your name: 
  <input type="text" id="id1">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**Output:**

I am getting only the content of My_formG.

But I need content from both to be displayed. (I think the content of the if block is getting overwritten by the form. Is it so??).

Comment: Did my changed code work for you?

Comment: Gnan, I tested the above code and it works as you want. Maybe there is something wrong with the rest of your code. Are you sure that $MyexceptionOverFlow has been set before it reaches the if statement?

Comment: Ya you are right, no issue with this code. The remaining code was not proper. Thanks to all of to pay you time to me. And sorry to tagged this question with out cross checking properly

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$MyexceptionOverFlow = 1;

if($MyexceptionOverFlow){ ?>
<div>
<?php echo " OVER FLOW EXCEPTION.......  "; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<form id="My_formG">
Enter your name:
<input type="text" id="id1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```